# T_VARIABLE parse error

Tags: php

I saw here about my problem [PHP Script to Edit DNS Records in CPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774194/php-script-to-edit-dns-records-in-cpanel) but When I try to use the dnsclass.php.
I can create a object like this:

```
$zones = new zone_records("cpaneluser", "pass", "website_to_login", "domain_of_records")
```

But I can't use this:

```
 $zones->addrecord($type, $target, $name, $ttl)
```

I'm having this problem :
            Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/mcser325/public_html/test.php

My code:

```
include 'classdns.php';
$zones = new zone_records("**", "**", "**", "**")
$zones->addrecord("**", "**", "**", "**")
```

Comment: PHP error messages show line numbers. Show us the line that's causing the error. If that's the line, it's probably the lack of semicolon.

Comment: And it's worth including a couple of lines either side of that one, too, as sometimes the error occurs elsewhere but the interpreter doesn't pick it up til later.

Comment: I edited the title because this has *nothing* to do with editing DNS records.

Comment: Ok. Sorry about the tittles. I wrote the code.

Comment: @user2577269 - yeah, you're missing your semicolons.

Comment: I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no semicolon at the end of the statement which is causing the error.

Comment: Omg that is right.. I didnt see it.. Thanks (:

Comment: You're welcome. If you find an answer useful you can accept it by clicking on the "tick" on the left side. :)