# How does DNS editor works?

Tags: php, dns

I would like to know how does this class from:[PHP Script to Edit DNS Records in CPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774194/php-script-to-edit-dns-records-in-cpanel) posted by: Scott.

I would like to know how can I use this:

```
     $zones->addrecord($type, $target, $name, $ttl)
```

Because Im having this problem when I try to put the right name:

Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid name 'teste'..

I tried:

```
 $zones->addrecord('A', 'ip','somename', 14400)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For you to consider, [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)? What research have you done? (consider this and update your question)

Comment: Ok.I wrote what I tried. Sorry

Comment: Have you read the code you're working with? you're hitting line `84` which throws an exception that you don't catch.

Comment: Yes I have read.I saw there, the line is:


        if (!preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*".preg_quote($this->zonedomain)."\.$/", $name)) {
   throw new Exception("Invalid name '$name'", 0); }

Comment: have you tried: `$zones->addrecord('A', '<ip>', 'somename.<domain>.', 14400)`? The regex is checking for the zone domain too